# Communication between microservices using Feign throws bean could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, feign

I'm trying to get my microservice java spring boot to communicate with another microservice using Feign but I'm getting this message when starting the application:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description: Parameter 0 of constructor in ProductService required a bean of type ProductClientRepository' that could not be found.

Action: Consider defining a bean of type 'ProductClientRepository' in your configuration.
```

I don't know what could be wrong, I already checked if all the declared variables are in the project's properties and I already checked the imports, I don't know why it is saying that something is missing in the bean.

pom.xml:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

SaleService:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SaleService {

 private final ProductService productService;

 @Transactional
    public Sale createSale(Sale sale) {

        Set<Long> codesFromRequest = sale.getProducts().stream().map(p -> p.getCode())
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        validateProduct(codesFromRequest);

       return saleRepository.save(sale);
       
    }

    public void validateProduct(Set<Long> codesFromRequest) {
        List<SaleProductDTO> products = productService.findProduct(codesFromRequest);

        Set<Long> returnedCodes = products.stream().map(p -> p.getCode()).collect(Collectors.toSet());

        throwExceptionIf(validateSizeList(codesFromRequest, returnedCodes),
                new ProductNotFoundException());
    }

    public boolean validateSizeList(Collection<?> codesFromRequest, Collection<?> returnedCodes) {
        return codesFromRequest.size() != returnedCodes.size();
    }

}
```

ProductService:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProductService {

    private final ProductClientRepository productRepository;

    @Retryable(value = { Exception.class }, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 50))
    public List<SaleProductDTO> findProduct(Set<Long> codes) {

        Page<SaleProductDTO> resultPage;

        try {
            var search = SearchProductDTO
                    .builder()
                    .codes(codes)
                    .build();

            resultPage = productRepository.getProducts(search);
        } catch (FeignException f) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        return resultPage.getContent();
    }
}
```

ProductClientRepository:

```
@FeignClient(name = "product-service", url = "${ms-product.url}", configuration = ProductOAuth2FeignConfig.class)
public interface ProductClientRepository {

    @GetMapping(value = "/chunk")
    Page<SaleProductDTO> getProducts(@RequestBody SearchProductDTO searchDTO);
}
```

ProductOAuth2FeignConfig:

```
public class ProductOAuth2FeignConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ProductConfig productConfig;

    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor stockOAuth2RequestInterceptor() {
        return new OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor(new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(), resource());
    }

    private OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource() {
        ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resource = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
        resource.setAccessTokenUri(productConfig.getTokenUri());
        resource.setClientId(productConfig.getTokenClientId());
        resource.setClientSecret(productConfig.getTokenClientSecret());
        resource.setGrantType(productConfig.getTokenGrantType());
        resource.setScope(List.of(productConfig.getTokenScope()));

        return resource;
    }
}
```

ProductConfig:

```
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ms-product")
public class ProductConfig {

    private String tokenUri;
    private String tokenGrantType;
    private String tokenClientId;
    private String tokenClientSecret;
    private String tokenScope;
}
```

application.properties:

```
external.api=https://myadress.com/api

ms-product.url=${external.api}/products
ms-product.token-uri=${external.api}/products/oauth2/token
ms-product.token-grant-type=client_credentials
ms-product.token-client-id=client-id-value
ms-product.token-client-secret=secret-value
ms-product.token-scope=read

feign.client.config.default.connect-timeout=3000
feign.client.config.default.read-timeout=7000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need to add @EnableFeignClients annotation. Please refer [Spring Boot OpenFeign](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/#netflix-feign-starter)